# MySQL select SUM when a table is joined

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.website, u.phone, SUM( r.redeem_amount ) , SUM( r.redeem_paid )
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN redeemed r ON u.user_id = r.redeem_user_id
WHERE r.redeem_state = '0'
GROUP BY u.website
```

What am trying to do, is to select the SUM of redeem amount from table redeem against each website, each website should be selected it's total (SUM) from redeem table

The provided query is able to select each website but failing to select SUM from table redeem as it is select only one row from redeem not total of that website.

Can I have your help or be pointed where am getting things wrong and how I can improve this. I know to some you may fee it simple but I can't get the trick as am not too advanced in MySQL.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d

Comment: Can you prefix each column in the select clause with `u` or `r` for clarification? (or better provide a sqlfiddle)

Comment: Group By what !! w ???

Comment: @abu sorry I press wrong key W instaed of u

Comment: @ RC I try that way still same results

Comment: Is user ID unique for each website ?

Comment: @abu ya, that's my primary key in table users, where it can be join with redeem table. user_I'd = redeem_user_id

Comment: Does Redeemed have the website as well or is it only on Users?

Comment: If you mean a columin redeem.website then no, the column is only user.website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Try to use the below :

> SELECT u.user_id, u.website, u.phone, SUM( r.redeem_amount ) , SUM(
>   r.redeem_paid ) FROM users u LEFT JOIN redeemed r ON u.user_id =
>   r.redeem_user_id WHERE r.redeem_state = '0' GROUP BY r.redeem_user_id

[image: Redeem Table]

[image: Users Table]

[image: Results]

Comment: Stil get the same as my query

Comment: Its Right @FetchLazy, and your above query right too, I Tested it on Navicat, check your condition r.redeem_state = '0'

Comment: Is it possible to see the results?

Comment: I think there is a problem with MySQL in the server I was running this cos it works on different machine , it took me to paste the dump and run the query on different machine to get successful results and stil the first machine is giving error. But I appreciate as I took my whole day trying it.